# How to search Amazon Cognito Identity?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In android application, i am setting Cognito identity as follows:

```
Dataset dataset = ....syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("WHATEVER");
dataset.put("name", name);
dataset.put("email", email);
```

As a result Identity Id is created in this format:

```
us-east-1:1xxxxxx-999d-999x-NNNx-fxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The Identity Browser on AWS Web Console allows one to search only by Identity Id.

Now i want to search the identity by email (because that's all i know about the user). How can i search the identity by email in amazon web-console?

Alternatively, can i set email id as the Identity Id itself - if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the only way to search an identity on the console is by identity id. We have heard the request from other customers to make it easier to search by another factor and will consider it in future updates to the service.

Comment: Is there a way to set a custom identity id (like email id or username) instead of generated one?

Comment: As of now there is not. Adding a logging mechanism could potentially help bridge this gap.

Comment: So what is the Unique User Identity here, how does it become available on another mobile device? I thought i could set user's email id, and then look it up from another device, to retrieve user data.

Comment: The identityId is a string generated by Cognito. In a given pool, it's unique for a login. So, if user A logs in with facebook on two devices for the same app, he'd get the same id. You appear to be using the android sdk, so it would be retrievable with a getCachedIdentityId() call against the credentials provider (after you've authorized the user).

Comment: In my Android Game, i maintain virtual coins for end user - this is stored in dataset record [COINS==90] of his congnito id. Now i want to give 10 additional coins to the end user as a bonus, he emailed me with his facebook email id - so thats what i have. I find no way to locate his congnito record/dataset, to allow for coin addition. What am i missing here?

Comment: The write access to the sync store needs an identity id. If you had saved the email to the dataset (as implied above), then it could be possible to check manually, but unfortunately you can only search by identity id as of now.

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do to retrieve the identityId, is to write a Lambda function that will stored the email address of your user along with the identityId in a DynamoDB table when the Cognito Sync Event is fired.

Doing this you can then search in DynamoB using the user email address to retrieve the IdentityID of the player.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for now is store that id and the email in your own database somewhere via your own API if you don't want to add AWS services. Or do what pierre-leduc said